# Transferring TON Crystals from Tonkeeper App to Huobi via API

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ton, huobi

I'm trying to figure out how to transfer TON Crystals (TONs) from the Tonkeeper App to Huobi using their respective APIs and JavaScript. I'm relatively new to working with blockchain-related transactions.

Specifically, I'd like to know the step-by-step process and the necessary code snippets to achieve this transfer. I assume I need to interact with the Tonkeeper API to initiate the transfer and then somehow utilize the Huobi API to handle the deposit on their platform.

If anyone has experience with these APIs and could provide guidance, I would greatly appreciate it. Code examples or pseudo-code outlining the necessary steps would be incredibly helpful. Thank you in advance for your assistance!